# pandas resample irregular spaced time data

Tags: python, pandas

```
                  x1         x1.resample('1T').mean
ts

2017-09-09 17:22:42   7.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:22:53  11.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:23:04   9.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:23:15  15.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:23:26  13.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:23:38  19.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:23:49  13.0        NaN
2017-09-09 17:24:00  15.0  10.666667
```

the above is the result of `df.x1Avg = df.x1.resample('1T').mean()` the code only return result when the ts end in hh:mm:00. The result I want is

```
                      x1         x1.resample('1T').mean
ts

2017-09-09 17:22:42   7.0        (7+11)/2
2017-09-09 17:22:53  11.0        (7+11)/2
2017-09-09 17:23:04   9.0        (9+15+13+19+13)/5
2017-09-09 17:23:15  15.0        (9+15+13+19+13)/5
2017-09-09 17:23:26  13.0        (9+15+13+19+13)/5
2017-09-09 17:23:38  19.0        (9+15+13+19+13)/5
2017-09-09 17:23:49  13.0        (9+15+13+19+13)/5
2017-09-09 17:24:00  15.0        15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transform

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['mean'] = df.resample('1T').transform('mean')
```

You get

```
                     x1     mean
ts      
2017-09-09 17:22:42 7.0     9.0
2017-09-09 17:22:53 11.0    9.0
2017-09-09 17:23:04 9.0     13.8
2017-09-09 17:23:15 15.0    13.8
2017-09-09 17:23:26 13.0    13.8
2017-09-09 17:23:38 19.0    13.8
2017-09-09 17:23:49 13.0    13.8
2017-09-09 17:24:00 15.0    15.0
```

Comment: Thx so much it worked. Could you please explain to me why my previous does not work and what does transform do?

Comment: You were trying to resample on the series (df.x1.resample) but what you need is to resample the dates which are in the index and aggregate the values in x1. Only difference with transform is that i maintains the shape of the dataframe, df.resample('1T').mean() would return only 3 rows with mean values 9, 13.8 and 15